# How Can i Show Location with Marker on Map using longitude & latitude From Firestore Collection?

Tags: android

I had Stored longitude & latitude in Firestore Collection, How can i display location on Map using longitude & latitude

[image: please Guide me.]

Following is what I tried :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    collectionReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(18.5204, 73.8567)).title("pune"));
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(18.5204, 73.8567)).zoom(16).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried in code?

Comment: I want to plot marker on map by using lat,long which are strings in my collection. I have a mapview with one static marker. Is there any way I can get lat,long from firestore to map?

Comment: Can you add your code that your tried so far?

Comment: have added in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retrieve `latitude` and `longitude` from `QuerySnapshot` and then need to add this to marker. Check below:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    ....

    FirebaseFirestore mDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference mOrderRef = mDatabase.collection("Job Post1");

    mOrderRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if(documentSnapshot.contains("lat") && documentSnapshot.contains("lon")) {
                    String lat = (String) documentSnapshot.get("lat");
                    String lon = (String) documentSnapshot.get("lon");
                    String title = (String) documentSnapshot.get("title");

                    if(lat != null && lon != null && !lat.isEmpty() && !lon.isEmpty()) {
                        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat.trim());
                        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(lon.trim());

                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(title));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @shubham-shedge, Check my answer

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.part_time_job, PID: 8738
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at com.example.part_time_job.LabourFragment$2.onSuccess(LabourFragment.java:153)

Comment: at com.example.part_time_job.LabourFragment$2.onSuccess(LabourFragment.java:145)

Comment: Lat and lag are fetch from firestore but when we post new Job then new marker is override with old marker. i want  show multiple marker on map activity

Comment: @SHUBHAMSHEDGE, that is related to post. You ask question here related to fetch and show from firestore. I think this will resolve using above answer. Please accept the answer and then ask another with your code related to post. Hope you understand. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335122/plot-multiple-marker-on-map-view-using-longitude-latitude-from-firestore-cloud please check this Question